# Retag page needs more left padding?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It looks like the content area of the question retag page needs more padding-left. I'm using Firefox 8.0 on Oneiric.

[image]

Comment: Which version of which web browser are you using? (This may help the team reproduce your problem)

Comment: added browser to post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.